# Logical reasoning: What is the difference between NOT-elimination and False-introduction?

Tags: logic

What is the difference between derivation rules: NOT-elimination and False-introduction?

My book says they are similar, but they differ in use. I think my book lacks the description of the difference and also when to use which one.

I hope someone can answer my question including a example!

Comment: Which book are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ¬-Elim says that:

> If you have:                       ¬P ⊢ ⊥
>
> Then you can conclude:   ⊢ P

*Example.* Suppose that 3 is not odd(¬O). Derive a contradiction using some number-theoretic fact (⊥). Then by ¬-Elim you can conclude that the assumption (viz. ¬O) was false, so O is the case.

---

*Remark 1.* Treating negation in a special way we get the equivalent form:

> If you have:                       (P → ⊥) ⊢ ⊥
>
> Then you can conclude:   ⊢ P

Combining this with the deduction theorem, we get the equivalent:

> If you have:                       ⊢ (P → ⊥) → ⊥
>
> Then you can conclude:   ⊢ P

Which, once the negation is re-interpreted in classical terms, becomes:

> If you have:                        ⊢ ¬¬ P
>
> Then you can conclude:     ⊢ P

*Conclusion*. ¬-Elim and the rule of "double negation elimination" are the same thing.

---

The ⊥-Intro rule says this:

> If you have:                         ⊢ P   and    ⊢ ¬P
>
> Then you can conclude:    ⊢ ⊥

*Example*. (this one is more abstract). Suppose that you have been able to derive that some number k is prime (P). If you have also been able to derive that that k has, say three divisors (¬P), then you can appeal to ⊥-Intro to conclude that you have derived a contradiction (⊥). You can then appeal to the fact that you have proved ⊥ to conclude *any* sentence Q you want (by ⊥-Elim).

---

*Remark 2.* The ⊥-Intro rule can also be seen as an instance of *modus ponens* (→-Elim):

> If you have:                         ⊢ P   and    ⊢ (P → ⊥)
>
> Then you can conclude:    ⊢ ⊥

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But I meant the negation elimination, not the double negation elimination. Could you change your answer? My book says that one could conclude False from !P and P by both rules.

Comment: What does the Negation-Elimination rule say according to your book?

Comment: Okay, let me try something else. See if it's what you need.

Comment: It says: `|| || \n (k) !P \n || || \n P \n || || \n { !-elim on (k) and (l): } \n (m) False`. Sorry for the `\n`, you would have to format it yourself. Also the `!` should be the negation symbol. Looking at the False-introduction however it is completely the same, except the lines with `|| ||` consist of three vertical dots.

Comment: Check it out now.